# Bash line continuation with parameter expansion

Tags: bash, mkdir

This

`mkdir -p a/{b,c}`

makes the directory structure:

```
a
|-- b
`-- c
```

However, this

```
mkdir \p a/{ \
   b, \
   c \
   }
```

causes this to happen:

```
|-- }
|-- a
|   `-- {
|-- b
|-- ,c
```

Why is that? Is there a fix?

Comment: Maybe some Linux guru can understand that, but it would be much more readable if you copy and paste from your terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have unquoted spaces in brace expansions. This will cause the brace expansion to fail and instead be passed as a literal strings (which is why you instead create directories named `}`).

It works if you delete all the spaces:

```
mkdir -p a/{\
b,\
c\
}
```

Comment: Phooey :(  that messes up my nice formatting with the indentation. But with a lot of directories, I might still like it better than on one line.

Comment: You could use nested loops instead